# Rails: page is idle and unclickable after modal form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a form inside a `bootstrap modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="form_modal" tabindex='-1'>
  <%= simple_form_for @detail_question, remote: true do |f| %>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Question</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <%= f.error_notification %>
          <div class="form-inputs">
            <span> <span id="characterLeft"></span>.</span>
            <%= f.input :content, label: false %>

          </div>
          <div id="formModal">
            <%= render partial: 'layouts/messages' %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <%= f.button :submit, "Ask", class:" btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Controller create method:

```
def create
  @detail_question = DetailQuestion.new(question_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @detail_question.save
      flash.now[:success] = "Question was successfully sent!"
      format.js { render 'create.js.erb' }
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Something went wrong!"
      format.js { render 'create.js.erb' }
    end
  end
end
```

create.js.erb

```
<% if @detail_question.save %>
  $("#flash").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'layouts/messages') %>");
  $("#detail_questions_<%= @detail_question.product.id %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'detail_questions/detail_questions', locals: { product: @detail_question.product } ) %>");
<% else %>
$("#formModal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'layouts/messages') %>");
<% end %>
```

When I submit the form, the modal closes and creates the question, renders the flash message and also renders the partial like its suppose to. But the only bug I'm having... is that the page loads as unclickable and idle, please look at the image below.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any errors in js console? What is in your rails server log for create action?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Vasilisa, nope absolutely none... that's the weird part, it should be rendering the partial fully. Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Hey @Vasilisa, do you think this issue is because of turbolinks?

Comment: Not sure. Try to remove all from `create.js` and leave there only `alert('It works')` line

Comment: I did and the alert does show when I submit the form.

Comment: And is the page still idle and unclickable?

Comment: Well the modal doesn't disappear after I submit the form, but when I added a close button to the modal it is clickable. But I don't want a close button on the modal, I want it close automatically and renders the ajax.

Comment: Looks like you need to close modal window in your `create.js.erb` file

Comment: Do u know how I can do that  do that? `$('#myModal').modal('hide')` something like this?

Comment: Its working with the alert but when I add the `$('#myModal').modal('hide')` to the other ajax code I have in create, unfortunately it has the same behaviour!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189725/discussion-between-vasilisa-and-dev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short - problem was in modal backdrop. Solved by adding

```
$('#form_modal').modal('hide') 
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

to create.js.rb